# При шеринге в вк в личных сообщениях экранируется emoji и символ, добавленный через юникод

Tags: vkontakte-api, unicode, sharing

Вставляю в title шера в вк символ юникодом (пробовала и обычным emoji), но если я делюсь в личных сообщениях в вк этим шефом, то он экранизирует и сердце выглядит как юникод (в title видим  его в виде юникода ❤  ️), то есть вижу &#10 0 8 4;  &#6 50 3 9; (убрать пробелы)
Можно что-то с этим сделать? Если «поделиться» на стене, то все ок

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это баг в ВК, самостоятельно это не поправить.